# How to get gmail address through adb shell on google glass

Tags: adb, google-glass

I manage a small project where I occasionally distribute a different version of a google glass application to some (4) google glass devices manually through the adb shell. One version of the package is used for each google glass, and it depends on which gmail address the glass uses. (they all look the same)

Usually I would have to turn on the glass to see, but I was looking for a method of getting the gmail address associated with the glass through the adb shell. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way I know to retrieve such info about the user.
But, you can simply put a file in the external storage containing the email account once, and then query this file when you want:

```
# write the user info
adb shell "echo \"xyz@gmail.com\" > /sdcard/user.info"

# get the user info
adb shell cat /sdcard/user.info
```

If you want this info without turning the glass on, you'll have to print a note directly on the glass ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `adb` command, one way to differentiate each Glass device is through their [serial numbers](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#devicestatus). You can then choose which device to install on by running the following command:

`adb -s <serial number> install <apk name>.apk`